Github actions CI/CD pipeline is unable to retrieve environment variables from cypress.config.ts
In my GitHub Actions CI/CD pipeline, there is a step for Cypress end-to-end tests that uses the command npx nx run ${{ inputs.repo_project_name }}:e2e.
My end-to-end tests are failing because they are unable to retrieve environment variables. The end-to-end tests run successfully locally but fail to execute in the CI/CD GitHub Actions environment.
Here is my Cypress configuration file:
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import { nxE2EPreset } from '@nx/cypress/plugins/cypress-preset';
import { nxComponentTestingPreset } from '@nx/next/plugins/component-testing';

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    ...nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename),
  },
  e2e: {
    ...nxE2EPreset(__filename, { cypressDir: 'cypress' }),
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4201',
    pageLoadTimeout: 100000,
    env: {
      JDC_ALIAS: 'http://localhost:4201',
      CYPRESS_UAM_BASE_URL: process.env.CYPRESS_UAM_BASE_URL,
      CYPRESS_UAM_BASIC_AUTH: process.env.CYPRESS_UAM_BASIC_AUTH,
    },
  },
});

Could someone help me understand why the environment variables are not being retrieved and how to resolve this issue?
I was expecting that by writing npx nx run ${{ inputs.repo_project_name }}:e2e this command end to end test will run fine
I tried passing --env in the command, and it worked fine. However, if there are more than four environment variables, the command would become unwieldy. Is there a better approach to handle this?

In your GitHub Actions workflow file (.github/workflows/your-workflow.yml), ensure that the environment variables are correctly defined.

They’ve identified that the issue is that their environment variables aren’t being imported, so I don’t see how this helps them.
